# Event tracking Google Tag Manager in browser

Tags: google-analytics, e-commerce

How can I track the requests Google Tag Manager in browser (not extension, in tab Network)

Comment: Your question is somewhat unclear (partly because of broken grammar and partly because you ask about Google Tag Manager in a question that is tagged Google Analytics).  Can you clarify ?

Answer (score 0):

Google Tag Manager makes only one request (to load the js file that has the configured tags), all other requests come from the tags within GTM and you'd need to know their respective endpoints to monitor them in the network tab.

If you want to keep track of what GTM does you can watch the dataLayer variable in the console. Every fired tag will correspond to an event that is pushed to the dataLayer (the DL is a JSON object and the current event will be added as a new element to the end of the object).

Answer (score 0):

Yes if you type dataLayer in the console (it should autofill). You can get a view of all dataLayer events fired.

This lets you know what is currently in the dataLayer.